# handle scrapy exception CloseSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import csv
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']

    start_urls = ['http://www.google.com/search?q=summer&hl=en&num=40']

    def __init__(self,stats):
        self.stats = stats
        SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).connect(receiver=self._close, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).connect(receiver=self._open,signal=signals.spider_opened)

    def _open(self):
        #os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        self.input_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Please Select Keywords File', filetypes=[('CSV files', ('.csv'))])
        if not self.input_file:
            raise CloseSpider(reason='no_file')

    def _close(self):
        print("done")
```

I get this error if no file is given, what I want is to simply close the spider with no error showing. How can I handle this exception [Exceptions](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html), I read from doc this is how you close spider it doesn't mention how to deal with it

```
2019-08-10 14:55:56 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method GoogleSpider._open of <GoogleSpider 'google' at 0x7fd56b6eda58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/timmy/spiders/google.py", line 61, in _open
    raise CloseSpider(reason='no_file')
scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider
```

Comment: What is your Scrapy version?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that is supported at the moment.

Alternatively, you could set `self.start_urls = []` instead, with a similar result.